# Can't read text file from desktop using objective-c

Tags: objective-c

**Can anyone help me to find what's wrong with my code while reading file from desktop**

```
    NSString *filename=@"~/Users/user12345/Desktop/Sample/Data.txt";
    NSString *fileString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filename encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSArray *namesArray=[fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    for(NSString *names in namesArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"names:%@",names);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the tilde – which represents `/User/<currentUser>/` – you have to *...expandingTildeInPath* and remove `/Users/user12345`

```
NSString *filename = [@"~/Desktop/Sample/Data.txt" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
```

that makes the path independent of the current user name, otherwise remove the tilde:

```
NSString *filename = @"/Users/user12345/Desktop/Sample/Data.txt";
```

Caveat: If your app is sandboxed the path does not point to the *visible* desktop.

Comment: what is this exactly means: Caveat: If your app is sandboxed the path does not point to the visible desktop.    And yes even this didn't worked for me. I am unable to fetch from terminal too though i created that file just now.

Comment: If the app is sandboxed then the path points to the desktop **in the sandbox container** of the app. The terminal is not sandboxed. If it doesn't work in Terminal then there is something wrong with the absolute path or the file. Nevertheless `~/Users/<currentUser>` won't work in Terminal.app either.

Comment: well thanks for the help. Now i can fetch the data in terminal but still facing problem while running in Xcode                                          NSString *filename=[@"~Users/user127868/Desktop/Sample/Data.txt" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
        NSString *fileString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filename encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        
        NSArray *namesArray=[fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
        
        for(NSString *names in namesArray)
        {
            NSLog(@"names:%@",names);
        }

Comment: Let me know whether i can do any modifications

Comment: Please re-read my answer carefully. Either use the tilde **without `Users/user127868`**  or use the full path starting with a slash **without tilde**

Comment: Thank you so much , It worked. I just added slash in front of the full path :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *filename=@"~/Users/user12345/Desktop/Sample/Data.txt";
```

The `~` used in a path is a convention which means your home directory, but it doesn't work in all contexts (e.g. when used in -stringWithContentsOfFile:`) and you've supplied an absolute path anyway. Remove it from the front of your path

```
NSString *filename=@"/Users/user12345/Desktop/Sample/Data.txt";
```

and it should work as long as the file does actually exist at that path.

Comment: Tried this too but no use. I can't even fetch that path from terminal too.           open ~/Users/user12345/Desktop/Sample/Data.txt . Can you tell me what might be my exact problem.

Comment: Well obviously it will fail if the file doesn't exist! Anyway, look at @vadian's answer. It's more robust in general.

Comment: @Gree Also in the terminal the `~` always expands to your home directory. `open ~/Users/user12345/Desktop/Sample/Data.txt` is the same as `open /Users/yourusername/Users/user12345/Desktop/Sample/Data.txt`